# How to Calculate csc(2.85) in Calculator?

Tags: trigonometry

In my calculator (TI-84), there are only $sin, cos,$ and $tan$ commands (and inverse sin, inverse cos, inverse tan). I had a question that was as follows:

Calculate $csc(2.85)$ in which I was permitted use of the TI-84 calculator.

As $csc$ is the inverse of $sin$, I wrote $csc(2.85) = 1/sin(2.85)$, which came out to be $3.4785,$ which I believe to be the right answer. I wanted to take $csc^{-1}$ of $3.4785$ to check my answer, however when I did so, the answer came out to be $0.29159$ rather than $2.85.$

I checked with other random numbers that taking the inverse of the answer should give the correct number of radians back. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Recall that $\csc x=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$. You can compute the inverse values of the form $\csc^{-1}x$ using $\sin^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but instead of 2.85 I got 0.29159, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, the problem you're faced with has to do with the domain of the inverse functions. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ArcCsc%5BCsc%5B2.85%5D%5D%2C+Pi-ArcCsc%5BCsc%5B2.85%5D%5D)

Comment: Oh, I see. So the 2.85 would be other answer, in other words .29159 is not an incorrect return. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure your calculator is set to radians ;)

Comment: the $\arcsin(x)$ is not a periodic function as the $\sin(x)$ function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y=\csc(x)$ is a function, so there is only one solution to $\csc(2.85) = 3.4785$. However, if you take the inverse of the cosecant function, you will obtain the graph:

[image: graph of y=arccsc(x)]

One can see that a vertical line at $x=3.4785$ will obtain a value just a bit bigger than $0$ and another value that is just a bit smaller than $\pi$. In fact, there will be an infinite number of values if the graph is $y=\csc^{-1}(x)$ because the graph is periodic in the vertical direction, that is, if the graph is not bounded by $y=\pm \frac\pi 2$. Hence, the general equation for the solution set is
$$y=\csc^{-1}(x)+2n \pi \quad \text{or} \quad \pi - \csc^{-1}(x)+2n \pi \quad, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
In this case specifically,
$$y=\csc^{-1}(3.4785)+2n \pi \quad \text{or} \quad \pi - \csc^{-1}(3.4785)+2n \pi \quad, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\Rightarrow y=0.29159 \quad \text{or}\quad \pi - 0.29159 = 2.85$$

Answer (score 1):

$\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$

So $\csc(2.85)=\frac{1}{\sin(2.85)}$

Recall that $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the correct method, which is what I used. My question is why it didn't work when I plugged it into the inverse.

Comment: What is the point here of the last line? It's not needed to calculate the result.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\frac{1}{sin(2.85} \approx 3.4785$, then he got $csc^{-1}=0.29159$ which means $\frac{1}{sin(0.29159)} \approx 3.4785$. So $sin(2.85)=sin( \pi - 2.85) \approx sin(0.29159)$.

Which is what was troubling him.

Comment: I think a valid point is that, if elaborating on the relevance of $\sin x = \sin(\pi - x)$ is helpful, why not include it in the answer?